# Connection reset, only from one machine, only to certain websites, and only some of the time

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking

I am truly baffled.

I am a programmer who primarily programs in Rust.  I first noticed this problem when I noticed Cargo (Rust's package manager and build system) was having trouble downloading dependencies, failing with a connection reset error.  Curl exhibited this problem too, although my browser seemed to be unaffected.  Examining the output of curl -v I learned that DNS resolution succeeded, the connection to port 443 was successfully established, and then Curl got an ECONNRESET before sending the first byte.

After doing more testing, I noticed that Curl was able to access google.com, stackoverflow.com, python.org, ruby-lang.org, rust.facepunch.com (the site for the videogame), and lib.rs (a site detailing Rust libraries that is not itself affiliated with the Rust project) with no issues, but was blocked trying to connect to crates.io, rust-lang.org, rustup.rs, or docs.rs.  Stranger still, connections to these blocked sites would succeed seemingly at random approximately 17% of the time (measured by a batch script that tried over and over 1000 times in a row), and that once a connection had succeeded it could remain open indefinitely.  After probing further still, I noticed that connections from Firefox and MSEdge would get reset too, but only when accessing the http version of the website, not https (curl and cargo were blocked on both).  None of the other machines on my network are affected in the slightest.  I have no explanation for this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... if you look at the TCP RST packets in Wireshark, what IP TTL do they have (in comparison to the legitimate TCP packets arriving from the exact same site)? That's one way of narrowing down where along the path the RSTs might've been generated. (Although my main guess is one of the NAT gateways, either your own router or maybe the ISP's CGNAT system, putting a hard limit on concurrent connections you can open.)

Comment: One point that's common to all the sites that don't work, is that their certificates were issued by Amazon (RSA 2048 bits). All of the sites that work well have certificates by other issuers. I don't know why your curl would refuse Amazon certificates, but to test if this is indeed the problem use `curl -k` to disable SSL certificate checks.

Comment: @harrymc I like your theory, but if that were the case, HTTP traffic would get through fine -- at least enough to get a 301 redirect to the HTTPS site.  Also, the connection reset happens before the SSL handshake can complete -- before it can even begin.  curl gets ECONNRESET as soon as it tries to send the first byte.  I tried curl -k anyway for a lark -- no joy.

Comment: Actually scratch that -- I just had a look in Wireshark and the HTTP GET request or TLS handshake do go out before the reset comes in. @u1686_grawity -- the reset has a hop limit of 55 and appears to be coming from the target server.  I have no idea what to make of this.  To rule out your theory, I disconnected from WiFI and tried again connected to my phone's USB tether (essentially having it emulate a WiFi adapter connected to the same network my laptop was) and to my shock, it worked.  I'm a few more surprises like that away from believing in ghosts.

Comment: I also had curl make a cleartext HTTP request omitting the Host header to see if whatever it was was scanning that, and still got blocked.

Comment: If all these sites are on Amazon, seems like Amazon blocked your IP segment.

Comment: @harrymc If that was true, other machines on my network wouldn't be able to access the affected sites.

Comment: Which other machines? And what is different about yours?

Comment: As mentioned, this is the only machine on my network having this issue.  I have tried connecting my phone to my laptop in tethering mode, effectively making it a fancy WiFi adatper on the exact same network, and the problem goes away.  The problem also goes away with the laptop's built-in wifi adapter if Windows is booted in safe mode.